# Function that returns all the groups in CKAN

Tags: ckan

I wanted to know if anyone knows how to write a function in CKAN that returns all the groups in CKAN.

There is an example in the example_theme (but not working for me), something like this (inside the helpers.py):

```
def most_popular_groups():
    '''Return a sorted list of the groups with the most datasets.'''
    # Get a list of all the site's groups from CKAN, sorted by number of
    # datasets.
    groups = toolkit.get_action('group_list')(
        data_dict={'sort': 'packages desc', 'all_fields': True})

    # Truncate the list to the 10 most popular groups only.
    groups = groups[:10]

    return groups
```

However, this did not work out for me.

I am calling this function inside:

featured_group.html

```
{% set groups = h.most_popular_groups() %}

{% for group in groups %}
  <div class="box span3">
    {% snippet 'snippets/group_item.html', group=group, truncate=50, truncate_title=35 %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

group_item.html:

```
{% block group_item %}
  <section class="group-list module module-narrow module-shallow">
    {% block group_item_header %}
      <header class="module-heading">
        {% set truncate=truncate or 0 %}
        {% set truncate_title = truncate_title or 0 %}
        {% set title = group.title or group.name %}
        {% block group_item_header_image %}
          <a class="module-image" href="{{ h.url_for(controller='group', action='read', id=group.name) }}">
            <img src="{{ group.image_display_url or h.url_for_static('/base/images/placeholder-group.png') }}" alt="{{ group.name }}" height="150pt" width="150pt"/>
          </a>
        {% endblock %}

        {% block group_item_header_title %}
          <h3 class="media-heading"><a href="{{ h.url_for(controller='group', action='read', id=group.name) }}">{{ group.title or group.name }}</a></h3>
        {% endblock %}
        <!--
        {% block group_item_header_description %}
          {% if group.description %}
            {% if truncate == 0 %}
              <p>{{ h.markdown_extract(group.description)|urlize }}</p>
            {% else %}
              <p>{{ h.markdown_extract(group.description, truncate)|urlize }}</p>
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    -->
      </header>
    {% endblock %}
    <!--
    {% block group_item_content %}
      {% set list_class = "unstyled dataset-list" %}
      {% set item_class = "dataset-item module-content" %}
      {% snippet 'snippets/package_list.html', packages=group.packages, list_class=list_class, item_class=item_class, truncate=120 %}
    {% endblock %}
    -->
  </section>
{% endblock %}
```

However, it gives me the 500 server error.

Please, can anyone help me with this?
I just wanted to show all the groups using this function

update: my apache2 log says the following:

> [Tue May 09 09:44:40.806982 2017] [:error] [pid 9054:tid
>   140156479076096] [remote 127.0.0.1:51908] HelperError: Helper
>   'get_all_groups' has not been defined.

Where can I define the get_all_groups function? just create a new python file? how can I call it from the view featured_group.html ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: What does the 500 error stack trace says on the server?

Comment: it says: [Tue May 09 09:44:40.806982 2017] [:error] [pid 9054:tid 140156479076096] [remote 127.0.0.1:51908] HelperError: Helper 'get_all_groups' has not been defined. Where can I define the get_all_groups function? just create a new python file? how can I call it from the view featured_group.html ?

Comment: This is the key information - please edit the question and include it there

Comment: ok added to the question, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks plausible. The error you put in a comment suggests you're having problems defining the helper code.

To define a template 'helper' (i.e. so you can run python code in a template):

1. In your extension create a `helpers.py` file (e.g. in the same directory as plugin.py) and write your helper function there. See example: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/cc6cb3e3892714c8b4c574c024fc2e7243834f40/ckanext/harvest/helpers.py
2. In your extension's `plugin.py` your plugin class needs `p.implements(p.ITemplateHelpers)` then a get_helpers() method that names and points to your helpers function.  See example: https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest/blob/cc6cb3e3892714c8b4c574c024fc2e7243834f40/ckanext/harvest/plugin.py#L283-L294
3. Ensure you have enabled the plugin in your ckan config file (.ini) -
   i.e. list it in `ckan.plugins`.
4. Restart CKAN (e.g. apache or 'paster serve')

Now you can call the helper function in a template: `{{ h.<helper-name> }}` or like you have done.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I did it using another method. Thansk a lot for your time. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it finally connected all the dots which I had in my mind. +1